# Can Eclipse use the same sdk that Android Studio (intelliJ)?

Tags: eclipse, sdk, intellij-idea, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio, but I need Eclipse at the moment. So, in Window > Preferences > Android, in SDK Location, I choose the sdk location inside my Android Studio folder, that is .../android-studio/sdk, but it can't find the sdk APIs I've installed.

And when I try to enter this configuration, it shows:

```
The currently displayed page contains invalid values
```

Any help?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you *Need eclipse at the moment*? Stick with IntelliJ so that you can use android-studio w/o problems.

Comment: I need it because I have a project that is misconfigured in intelliJ, so it only runs in Eclipse.

Comment: To me it looks like the XY problem: [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Maybe the IntelliJ project can be fixed instead.

Comment: Download SDK http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html and install. Reference Eclipse and Android Studio to it.

Comment: Can you try an abusolute path to the SDK?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I know it is late for the answer but if anyone search for this..

First you have to set up a common SDK, for example put your SDK folder at the following location C:\Android\sdk

Link SDK in your Android Studio, go to `File->Project Structure->Android SDK` and point the C:\Android\sdk in Android SDK location.

Link SDK in your Eclipse ADT, go to `Eclipse->Preferences->Android` and change the SDK Location to C:\Android\sdk

*Restart both Eclipse and Android Studio

Comment: i'll try this option first before anythingelse. :D

Answer (score 7):

Yes, first install the Android studio. It will instal the SDK in an Android folder under   user/AppData/Local/Android/sdk 
then install Eclipse (unzip). Add the ADT (Android Dev Tools) to Eclipse see : http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Then, once you restart eclipse it will ask you to provide the folder for the SDK, provide the folder where Studio installed it.

There, both are working with same SDK.

This will save you space on the drive and not have to download and install the SDK twice.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy your -- .../android-studio/sdk and paste it outside of Android Studio app location, something like /Users/Name/sdk. Then point this /Users/Name/sdk path to eclipse. I think this will solve the problem.