# Is it possible to re-use sdk originally used by Eclipse ADT in Android Studio?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I found posts that indicate that the sdk used by Android Studio can also be used by Eclipse ADT.

[Can Eclipse use the same sdk that Android Studio (intelliJ)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846160/can-eclipse-use-the-same-sdk-that-android-studio-intellij)

Is it possible for the sdk used originally by Eclipse ADT to be used by Android Studio?

I already have an up to date SDK which I use with Eclipse ADT.
I recently downloaded Android Studio.
Was wondering if I could use the pre-existing SDK that I used with Eclipse ADT,instead of downloading it all over again for Android Studio.

Comment: yes SDK is independent part from IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes absolutely you can. **The SDK is independent of the IDE** you are using.

I will explain you the steps to do it.

1) You need have the SDK so that it can be commonly used by both the IDEs.

Let say you want to put your new SDK at the following location: `/Users/Name/sdk.`

You can also use the SDK that came up with Eclipse or download a new one if you want (it's not necessary at all).

2) Android Studio can automatically find the location of your SDK, but you need to manually point it out if it can not.

[image]

You may also need to specify the SDK location for your project. In your Android studio project, go to File -> Project Structure -> Android SDK, and point to your new sdk folder location.

[image]

**Remember to restart Android studio after this.**

Comment: Glad it helped you. It would be awesome if you could upvote the answer too. It took a loot of time and effort to write such a detailed answer to help you.

Answer (score 1):

For example your SDK folder is at the  *D:\Android\SDK*

Link SDK in your Android Studio, go to *File->Project Structure->Android* SDK and point the *D:\Android\SDK* in Android SDK location.

***Restart  Android Studio***